# Put Magento attribute into static block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I would like to add attributes into a particular magento static block. Each product has a specific attribute that is assigned to it and I would like to display that attribute into a specific static block.

I have created the attribute set SIZECHART and added women-top, women-bottom  and assign to products. I have also created static block women-top, women-bottom. I have a separate static block called SiZE that I would like to display the information on product page when someone is viewing the product.
The current code I have is and it not working

```
<?php       
   $_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
?>
<?php $attributeValue = strtolower($product->getAttributeText('sizechart')); ?>
<?php $staticBlockIdentifier = "static_block_".$attributeValue; ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId(size)->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: If you use a product attribute then by definition it's not a "static" block. A widget might be more suitable.

Comment: new to magento see the widget settings  but I am not  sure how i would accomplished what i would like to  do, can you indulge me

Answer (score 0):

Check if the attributive is correctly configured.
Check attribute configuration value *Visible on Product View Page on Front-end* put in YES

Comment: The configuration that I  have is as you stated plus i have the attribute names  set as the same names as the static block. The code I have use is posted  in view.phtml. However, nothing is displaying  in the static block called SIZE on product page

Comment: So if you currently are in the view.phtml no need to create again the product obj. Please try to debug and print in you instance getData() and check if the information is showing of SIZECHART

Comment: I will try that however, is the code that i have used posted above it it correct?

Comment: One moment, try to change $product with $_product bc you are creating a new instance of the product ($_product) but not using in the next line when you collect the attribute text value. About how your code is created, well I would have done in other way, first of all what you are creating a new instance of the same product you are in the view.phtml etc.

Comment: what would you  do differently as my way is not working

Comment: @chad on your code you create $staticBlockIdentifier but when you call the static block identifier you use size, use you variable created.

Comment: @chad any update?

Comment: I have  updated the coded as suggested, there is still no displaying of anything in static block SIZE.

Comment: @chad OK, share with me the name of the static blocks (identifier) and check if the static bloc is enables and visible In the scope store view you are trying to display (if you already have a more than 1 store view)

Comment: made some minor changes as was testing. updated changes are the static block with (identifier)  block_product_tab1  its visible and Displaying in the default store view. and i also have two other store views Name  Amazon US code name amazon_us and Name Ebay us with code name ebay_us

Comment: Please refrain from extensive chat in the comments.